# When connecting to TFS2010 server ,VS2010 always crashed without any error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I was working on VS2010 with TFS 2010. Everything is OK until our TFS server power outage. When connecting to server again,VS always crashed. Now we had to keep on offline mode. Restart the server serval times, nothing worked.

Comment: Could you provide more detail information? This happened only on your VS or including  all your colleagues'.

Comment: This only happened on my VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To narrow down your issue, you can try below methods:

- Load the web portal in a browser (Judge whether its related to TFS server)
- Connect to TFS with another user account on another machine.
- Clear TFS local cache
  http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx  and `VS cache` in `appdata` folder.
  For TFS 2010 the default path: `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache`

If you still can't solve it, check Event log which related to TFS. Also go through [VS logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) looking for the connection attempt and rejection reason.

Comment: Many thanks, finally reinstall VS , everything is back on track